# Auto-save plus browser refresh

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to configure VS 2010 to auto-save `cshtml`/`css`/`js` files on edit and refresh page in Chrome like in last version of WebStorm? It would be much more comfortable to work on split-screen or 2 monitors.